# Subdirectories in checked out directory of a previous revision not disappearing in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, git-checkout

I'm trying to use `git checkout <hash> <directory>` to checkout a previous revision of a directory in my repo.  This works to restore the files in the directory to their previous state, the only problem is that subdirectories that were added since the revision I checked out don't disappear.

For example, if my directory structure were the following:

```
HEAD:
thing/dir1/
thing/dir2/

HEAD^:
thing/dir1/
```

If I do `git checkout <hash>`, then I go into detached HEAD mode and everything matches fine.  If instead I do `git checkout <hash> thing/`, the contents of `thing/dir1/` will revert, but `thing/dir2/` will stay put.

Running `git status` shows the file modifications from `thing/dir1/`, but doesn't mention `thing/dir2/`.  This is weird, because in the context of HEAD^, `thing/dir2/` shouldn't exist and should therefore be gone.  `git clean` doesn't help because it doesn't even show up as untracked.

Is there a way to checkout a previous revision of a directory which perfectly matches, without having to checkout the entire working tree?

**UPDATE:**

Looks like this will work:

```
git reset <hash> thing/
git checkout <hash> thing/
git clean -fd thing/
```

This leaves my working tree and index in a strange state, but has the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout:

> Updates files in the working tree to
>   match the version in the index **or the
>   specified tree**. If no paths are given,
>   git checkout will also update HEAD to
>   set the specified branch as the
>   current branch.

Further below it also says:

> When < paths > or --patch are given, git
>   checkout **does not switch branches**. It
>   updates the named paths in the working
>   tree from the index file or from a
>   named  (most often a
>   commit). In this case, the -b and
>   --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an
>   error. The  argument can be
>   used to specify a specific tree-ish
>   (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update
>   the index for the given paths before
>   updating the working tree.

In other words, since you are not switching branches, the working directory will not reflect any changes to the HEAD pointer, but will show files that belong to the tree-ish, in this case it's HEAD^

The reason why thing/dir2 is still left on disc is that it still belongs to current HEAD (remember, HEAD is not moved) and there is no information in the tree-ish whats missing from the three-ish (in this case thing/dir2). So in effect you have thing/dir1 checked out to reflect the state of the HEAD^ hash and also thing/dir2 on disc since it belongs to HEAD.

Comment: This makes sense, but is there a way to do it then?  I basically want the effect of moving the HEAD pointer back for one directory only.  Deleting the directory manually and checking out as suggested by another answer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You already have this effect, the contents of thing/dir1 should reflect that you have "moved" HEAD for this folder.

Comment: If you really need to have thing for HEAD^ you should consider doing checkout without using the path argument. I dont know your reasons for wanting to do this the other way. Why is it so bad to just checkout the previous commit? You could probably use git archive and output it to another folder, if you really need the thing-subtree to match the exact commit, and not having to checkout the complete repository on HEAD^

Comment: I am using a single git repo to control separate design libraries. It would be convenient to be able to check out a single library as a different revision. Git almost manages this except for this problem.

Comment: Ok, it looks like if I really want to do this, I need to first do a reset, then checkout, then clean. Feels dirty, but works. I wonder if there's a cleaner way...

Comment: Don't forget that you can make it into a script and then you have a one liner :)

Answer (score 1):

As you already mention `git checkout <hash>` makes git go into *detached head mode*. When checking out particular files really only the files are copied into your working directory and everything else is untouched.

Thus the files in `thing/dir2/` don't show up in `git status` because they are in the current state of `HEAD` while `thing/dir1` will show modified files.

If you really want to have the whole `thing/` folder like in the last revision why not just delete it before?

```
rm thing/
git checkout <hash> thing/
```

I am not sure if it matches your needs. Use with caution! (Although when having no local uncommited changes everything *should* be restoreable.)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea but when I tried it, oddly enough, `thing/dir2` popped back up again.